# Trouble understanding pseudocode for Two-Pass Connected Components

Tags: image-processing, connected-components

I'm having some trouble understanding the wikipedia's pseudocode for connected-components labeling using Two-Pass algorithm. Here's the pseudocode:

```
algorithm TwoPass(data) is
linked = []
labels = structure with dimensions of data, initialized with the value of Background

First pass

for row in data do
    for column in row do
        if data[row][column] is not Background then

            neighbors = connected elements with the current element's value

            if neighbors is empty then
                linked[NextLabel] = set containing NextLabel
                labels[row][column] = NextLabel
                NextLabel += 1

            else

                Find the smallest label

                L = neighbors labels
                labels[row][column] = min(L)
                for label in L do
                    linked[label] = union(linked[label], L)

Second pass

for row in data do
    for column in row do
        if data[row][column] is not Background then
            labels[row][column] = find(labels[row][column])

return labels
```

My problem is with the line `linked[NextLabel] = set containing NextLabel`. It never initializes the NextLabel and still uses it. Also, what does it mean by "set containing NextLabel"? I'm really confused by this code.

Comment: `NextLabel` should indeed be initialized, for example to 1. You need to understand the Union-Find algorithm to understand this (as that is what it is). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @CrisLuengo so the explanation for this line is in the Union-Find page?

Comment: The “ set containing NextLabel” is `find(NextLabel)`, with `find` one of the two key operations of the “Union-find” data structure.

Comment: @CrisLuengo oh, got it! Thanks!